# `MomentGeneratingFunction` producing a function with negative moments

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, probability-or-statistics

I'm getting moment generating function which is negative and all moments are $-\infty$ which seems wrong...1) is this a bug in `MomentGeneratingFunction`? 2) what is a good work-around?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
n = 2;
dist = TransformedDistribution[(2 x - 1)^4, 
   x \[Distributed] BetaDistribution[n/2, n/2]];
mgf = MomentGeneratingFunction[dist, u];
Limit[D[mgf, {u, #}], u -> 0, Direction -> "FromBelow"] & /@ Range[5]
(* {-\[Infinity], -\[Infinity], -\[Infinity], -\[Infinity], -\[Infinity]} *)
```

(This is the distribution of $x_1^4$ where $\mathbf{x}$ is taken uniformly from surface of sphere in 3D)

```
numSamples = 10000;
data1 = RandomVariate[dist, numSamples];
data2 = First[#]^4 & /@ RandomPoint[Sphere[n + 1], numSamples];
SmoothHistogram[{data1, data2}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

n = 2;
dist = TransformedDistribution[(2 x - 1)^4, 
   x \[Distributed] BetaDistribution[n/2, n/2]];
```

As a workaround: From the documentation for [`MomentGeneratingFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MomentGeneratingFunction.html), "MomentGeneratingFunction is an exponential generating function for the sequence of moments"

```
mgf[u_] = ExponentialGeneratingFunction[Moment[dist, r], r, u]

(* Gamma[1/4, 0, -u]/(4 (-u)^(1/4)) *)

seq = Limit[D[mgf[u], {u, #}], u -> 0, Direction -> "FromBelow"] & /@ Range[5]

* {1/5, 1/9, 1/13, 1/17, 1/21} *)

seq == (Moment[dist, #] & /@ Range[5])

(* True *)

coef[r_] = FindSequenceFunction[seq, r]

(* 1/(1 + 4 r) *)

coef[r] == Moment[dist, r]

(* True *)

Sum[coef[r]*u^r/r!, {r, 0, Infinity}] == mgf[u]

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's an unexpected use of `FindSequenceFunction`!

Comment: Problem with `MomentGeneratingFunction` reported as `Technical Support Case 5054108`